# Cannot POST /login - POST http://localhost:3000/login 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, passport.js, ejs

I'm serving my login form but for some reason can't POST to login and actually log in. I think it has something to do with my route folders, but I've tried several iterations of the routing and can't seem to figure it out. I keep receiving error POST http://localhost:3000/login 404 (Not Found).

My app runs on port 3000.

CRUD path: "Routes" folder-> artists.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const Artist = require('../models/artist');
const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');
const ExpressError = require('../utils/ExpressError');

/* lists artists from database */
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const artists = await Artist.find({});
    res.render('artists/index', { artists })
});

router.get('/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render('artists/new');
});

router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
res.render('artists/login');
})

/* shows specific artists that exist in database */
/* link - show.ejs */
router.get('/:id', catchAsync(async(req, res,) => {
    const artist = await Artist.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!artist) {
        req.flash('error', 'Cannot find that Artist');
        return res.redirect('/artists');
    }
    res.render('artists/show', { artist });
}));

/* artist edits form*/
router.get('/:id/edit', catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const artist = await Artist.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!artist) {
        req.flash('error', 'Cannot find that Artist');
        return res.redirect('/artists');
    }
    res.render('artists/edit', { artist }); 
}))

router.put('/:id', catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const artist = await Artist.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { ...req.body.artist });
    res.redirect(`/artists/${artist._id}`);
}))

/* creating a new artist */
router.post('/new', catchAsync(async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, username, password, location, genre, about, size } = req.body;
        const artist = new Artist({ email, username, location, genre, about, size });
        const registeredArtist = await Artist.register(artist, password);
        req.flash('success', 'Successfully signed up!');
        res.redirect(`/artists/${artist._id}`)
    } catch (e) {
        req.flash('error', 'Sorry, an artist with that email already exists');
        res.redirect('/artists');
    }
}));

/** Where I'm encountering my error **/
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { failureFlash: true, failureRedirect: '/login' }), (req, res) =>{
    req.flash('success', 'Welcome back!');
    res.redirect('/artists');
})

/* delete a post */
router.delete('/:id', catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const{ id } = req.params;
    await Artist.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    res.redirect('/artists');
}))


router.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
    next(new ExpressError('Page Not Found', 404))
})

router.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    const { statusCode = 500, message = 'Something went wrong' } = err;
    res.status(statusCode).render('error');
})

module.exports = router;
```

Here's the ejs form w/ path: "Views" folder-> "artists" folder-> login.ejs

```
<% layout('layouts/boilerplate')%>
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-xl-4 offset-xl-4">
            <div class="card shadow">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1571863533956-01c88e79957e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=80"
                alt="" class="card-img-top" />
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Login</h5>
                    <form action="/login" method="POST" class="validated-form" novalidate>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label class="form-label" for="artist[username]">Username</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="artist[username]" name="artist[username]" required autofocus>
                            <div class="valid-feedback">
                                Looks good!
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label class="form-label" for="artist[password]">Password</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="password" id="artist[password]" name="artist[password]" required>
                            <div class="valid-feedback">
                                Looks good!
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my app.js to display all routes. I also have "users" and "events". Only Users and Artists can login.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ejsMate = require('ejs-mate');
const catchAsync = require('./utils/catchAsync');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
const session = require('express-session');
const Artist = require('./models/artist');
const Event = require('./models/event');
const User = require('./models/user');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const eventRoutes = require('./routes/events');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/users');
const artistRoutes = require('./routes/artists');


const dbUrl = process.env.DB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/macro-tickets';

mongoose.connect(dbUrl, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", () => {
    console.log("Database connected");
});

const app = express();

app.engine('ejs', ejsMate);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

/* method override allows to serve put requests into the database */
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

const sessionConfig = {
    secret: 'thisshouldbeabettersecret!',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    }
}

app.use(session(sessionConfig))
app.use(flash());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    next();
})


app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Artist.authenticate()));

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.serializeUser(Artist.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Artist.deserializeUser());

app.use('/events', eventRoutes)
app.use('/users', userRoutes);
app.use('/artists', artistRoutes)


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Serving on port 3000')
})
```

The form is POSTing to '/login' but nothing is going through. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If to use this router you are calling it with

```
app.use("/your-route", require("../routes/artists.js")
```

the correct address would be `http://localhost:3000/your-route/login`.

In your case it seems I can think what you do:

```
app.use("/artists", require("../routes/artists.js")
```

then the post request would be `http://localhost:3000/artists/login`.

Comment: Thanks Jorge makes sense -- however, when I update the route to router.post('/artists/login', passport.authenticate..) the server still serves me localhost:3000/login. Any ideas why my updated POST won't go through properly?

Comment: And if I modify the ejs page post location to '/artists/login', this is the error I get: login:1 POST http://localhost:3000/artists/artists/login 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Can I assume correctly that you don't use any other get method outside of the path files? Can you update the question and show your express file? @econobro

Comment: I have get requests in two other routes - 1) events and 2) users. Similar format but added the app.js for additional context. Thanks Jorge!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,
Update this in your app.js file

> app.use(require('./routes/artists'))

then your request link will be like http://localhost:3000/login

Comment: Thanks for the response @dlyaswanth. Tried this but I get client-side flash "missing credentials", which I don't have as a return anywhere so I'm guessing it's one of the pre-built flash responses. Added my app.js above for context.

Comment: Hi @dlyaswanth - added above.